# How to make my Dell 1390 wlan minicard work

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers, dell

I have a dell laptop with at dell wireless 1390 wlan mini-card driver, when I installed Ubuntu side by side with Win7 I assume it was missing a wireless driver since that's what it said. Later on I reinstalled completely to ubuntu, and connected my laptop to a internet cable assuming it will get all the drivers from ubuntu servers/depositories.

So the problem now is that in the networking tab I dont even see a wireless connection option, when I go to System Settings -> Additional drivers, it shows me that im using Broadcom STA proprietary wireless driver. But I still don't see my Wireless connection.

I have looked for tutorials but they are mostly too old.

Can someone please provide me with a step by step guide or some guidance on how to fix this issue, or give me a link to a place where it's shown how to fix it.

The information that was required

```
roberts@roberts-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for roberts: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1c:23:29:51:ed
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.119 duplex=full firmware=5755m-v3.29 ip=192.168.0.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:44 memory:fe7f0000-fe7fffff
```

AND

```
roberts@roberts-Latitude-D630:~$ rfkill list all
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
roberts@roberts-Latitude-D630:~$
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the *Additional Drivers* window deactivate the STA driver.

Connect you D630 via a wired connection.

Install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

reboot

[source](http://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/ubuntu-11-10-getting-wireless-bcm4311-working/)

Comment: Also is there a way of including this firmware in my USB installation media, so the next time I install the from the USB I would gave the firmware installed or be able to install it without physical Internet connection.

Comment: that's a very good question... suggest ask it!

Comment: OK, I'll do just that.