# Vista to Ubuntu 12.04, no internet connectivity

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, internet, windows-vista

I'm new to Linux. This is my first time downloading another operating system to anything. I was pleased when I saw Ubuntu's capabilities and downloaded the .iso at once to try the live CD. When trying out the live CD I noticed that I didn't have any internet connection, but I just assumed that you couldn't use it while using the live CD. I installed Ubuntu on my Gateway Vista laptop after trying out it's features, rebooted, and logged in. My internet still doesn't work, and I've tried everything. I have a Verizon router by Actiontec, and I am assuming I need to install a new driver or firmware for it to work with the new operating system, or maybe I'm way off. I just don't know what else to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu buddy. Got a couple of questions: 1. Are you connected wired or wirelessly. 2. If you are wired is it an USB cable or an ethernet one. 3. If you are wirelessly does it have some password and/or did you install the proprietary drivers for the wireless card (Type additional drivers in Dash). 4. Is there a configuration that you did in Vista to get internet or is the connection automatically done. This will help in finding the answer for you.

Comment: Can you plug into a cable?

Comment: I'm not connected at all. My router doesn't show up in settings and I don't have an Ethernet cable to establish a wired connection. My wireless router has a WEP password setup. The connection was automatically done for me in Vista, I didn't have to configure anything manually. I went to "Additional Drivers" and the message it gave me was "Downloading package indexes failed, please check your network status. Most drivers will not be available." I clicked close and then a window opened that said "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system." Thanks for your help in this matter!

Comment: I tried to install the firmware package but it says that it doesn't exist. E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer. Same thing with b43-fwcutter. What next?

Comment: I'll be alright downloading the packages and their dependencies from this computer (Windows 7). I successfully installed the b43-fwcutter, but now I'm having trouble installing the firmware package. It sent me to a website saying that there was a newer version to install and when I went to it it downloaded a .tar file for me. What is this and how do I install it?

Comment: I did it. After hours and hours of leafing through google search after google search and you all helping me through this, I have internet connectivity. What finally did it for me was this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx it just works! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I summarized the discussion to an answer and deleted the comments for clean-up. Please up-vote and accept it (or edit it if you feel there is something wrong) to mark your question solved.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal

[image]

Type:

```
lspci -k
```

in the terminal

[image]

Post the results and we'll try and help.

Comment: garrett@garrett-MX8711:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: intelfb, i915
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Comment: Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp

Comment: 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

Comment: 00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)

Comment: Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel modules: leds-ss4200, iTCO_wdt, intel-rng
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)

Comment: Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel modules: i2c-i801
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 0465
 Kernel modules: wl, ssb
04:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: e100
 Kernel modules: e100

Comment: 04:09.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbusKernel modules: yenta_socket
04:09.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host ControllerSubsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
 Kernel modules: firewire-ohci
04:09.2 Mass storage controller: Texas Instruments 5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD)
 Subsystem: Gateway 2000 Device 0685
 Kernel driver in use: tifm_7xx1
 Kernel modules: tifm_7xx1

Comment: That's it! Sorry I don't know how to post the picture, I'm using another computer to post as it is...

Answer (score 0):

First try using the easy way and use the `additional drivers` utility.

Make a wired internet connection and fully update your system.

Next open the dash (by pressing the *windows / super* key).

Then type `additional drivers` and click on the *additional drivers* icon.

Finally install any additional drivers which are suggested.

[image]

Comment: I don't have an Ethernet cable so I can't establish the wired connection, but thank you for replying!

Answer (score 0):

You have a **Broadcom BCM4311** wireless chip. See these related questions:

- [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)
- [Dell 1390 wireless (BCM4311) Ubuntu 12.04 no wireless icon in unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139168/dell-1390-wireless-bcm4311-ubuntu-12-04-no-wireless-icon-in-unity)
- [Dell Upgrade to 13.04 & 13.10 No wifi, graphic card driver and bluetooth Problem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130477/dell-upgrade-to-12-04-lts-no-wifi-graphic-card-driver-and-bluetooth-problem)
- [Community tutorial on bcm43xx drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

In short you will have to download and install proprietary drivers. In case you are unable to establish a wired (Ethernet) connection to your router this can also be done from another computer or from Windows. See the following answer on how to download packages offline:

- [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)