# Ethernet *-network DISABLED

Tags: drivers, server, ethernet

Just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 on my laptop. The desktop version always had driver issues but only with WiFi not the ethernet, and I could just hard wire and install the proprietary drivers manually and it would work. But on my installed server I get no Ethernet connectivity.

`ifconfig` only shows `lo` for loopback an not `eth0` like usual.

```
lshw -C network

*-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
```

I tried

```
ifconfig up

up: error fetching interface information: device unknown
```

then

```
lsmod
```

showed that by b34 and b44 modules are there but they were showing 0 in the column for in USE and no programs were using them, but b44 was using another program.

=======================

UPDATE 1:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i -A2 net

05:00.0 Network Controller 0280 Broadcom Corporation, BCM4311 802.11B/G WLAN 14E4:4311 REV 01
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390WLAN mini card 102b:007
Kernel driver in use b43-pic-brige
Kernel module: ssb

08:00.0 Ethernet Controller 0200 Broadcom Corporation, BCM4401-B0 100BASE-TX 14E4:170C REV 02
Subsystem Dell Device 102B01f5
Kernel driver in use b44
```

thank you.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i -A2 net` to your post.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to fix this by doing:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Perhaps that'll help.

Comment: Thank you! I actually ended up doing this awhile back but because I was in school I didn't come around to update it. I cant 1 Up but I would if I had the rep.

It was my eth0 card i was trying to start up though so I used eth0 instead of wlan0.

Comment: I ran `iwconfig` to grab the interface name then `sudo ifconfig enp0s31f6 up`

Comment: Followed this article, worked like a dream - https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-18-04-19-04-with-wpa-supplicant

Comment: `ifconfig` was not available but `ip` was. I did `sudo ip link set eth0 up`, and `sudo dhclient eth0`. You can find the interface names with `ip a`, and potential renames (from e.g. eth0) with `dmesg | grep eth0`.

Comment: @Natim iwconfig shows `wifi`, but your `enp..` seems like `ethernet`. So do not get confused..

Answer (score 0):

Is your b44 controller blacklisted in a file under /etc/modprobe.d ?
If yes, does removing the lines in this file (or maybe the whole file) help?
I followed an advice to question [308958](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308958), and removed the whole bcmwl-kernel-source, which didn't complete cleanly (probably because a the chicken and egg issue that I did not have connectivity).