# Network interfaces not detected on 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet, interface

I am using LTS version 20.04 and for some reason the NetworkManager service disappeared from the system. I manually installed Network Manager service, but still cannot see a network interface detected. From ifconfig, I only see the loopback interface:

```
user-MS-7823:~$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 162358  bytes 11529428 (11.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 162358  bytes 11529428 (11.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

user-MS-7823:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I even tried `dmesg` command but none of the interfaces were detected in the output.

Edit: output of `lshw -C network`

```
user-MS-7823:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for uor: 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: d8:cb:8a:55:ef:d4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7200000-f7200fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:1b:21:b6:60:17
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=1.8-0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:f71c0000-f71dffff memory:f7100000-f717ffff ioport:c000(size=32) memory:f71e0000-f71e3fff memory:f7180000-f71bffff
```

Can anyone help me figuring out what could be the solution to connect/detect the interfaces?

Comment: Update Your question with the output of `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Added the output, thanks for the tip @MichalPrzybylowicz. Do you know if there is a way to enable these interfaces?

Comment: Try this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/341690/ethernet-network-disabled#513615

Comment: Thanks for that. Other than the status `DISABLED` gone, there seems to be no changes in the output of the same command. The system still does not have internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this and in my case switched nics which led to it being disabled. So, I had an existing static config but for the wrong interface. Once I got the interface name right in 01-network-manager-all.yaml I was all set.

Answer (score 0):

In my case of an Intel Crop Ethernet Controller I225-V I had to install the `linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-87-generic` package in Ubuntu, otherwise no driver was available.