# Ethernet connection disabled in Ubuntu 22.04 OS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, ethernet

Ethernet connection can't be detected in my PC with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS OS, this question is also similar to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341690/ethernet-network-disabled), even after trying the suggested answers the problem was not solved.

This is what I get when I run the command `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (11) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno2
       version: 00
       serial: 74:78:27:0b:62:45
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-69-generic duplex=full firmware=0.4-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:152 memory:c4400000-c441ffff
```

When I run the command `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`, I get the following error message:

```
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Comment: it does, the post is already cited on the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the selected answer on the following [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906636/ethernet-adapter-was-disable-on-ubuntu-17-04). It worked for me.

Edit file `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` and change its content from :

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

to :

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:ethernet,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

And then run :

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

That's all. Hope this works for you too