# After 12.04 installation on Dell Inspiron 1520, no wired connectivity

Tags: 12.04, installation, ethernet, wired

Obviously the installation CD could use the Ethernet connection.
However, it didn't install/configure it.

ifconfig -a only reports a 'lo' interface.

Fortunately, the usb device works...
Couldn't it be possible to copy the device from the installation CD?

```
$ nm-tool
NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected
$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A10 -i network
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: wl, ssb
```

OK, and the Ethernet controller is BCM4401-B0 (from grepping 14e4 in the output of lspci -vvnn)
Followed another thread which sent me to look at the content of /etc/network/interfaces
There was only lo. So I added there eth0, and restarted the networking service.
But it is now in stop/waiting mode...
Skipping service and using directly the init.d script is clearer:

```
Cannot find device "eth0"
```

Checked my box at work, and surprise: there's no eth0 interface defined in /etc/network/interfaces, which doesn't prevent ifconfig -a from reporting one...
Removed the 'auto eth0' I had previously added, which allows the restart but solves nothing. OK... now the LAN is not plugged.

Comment: Could you also add `nm-tool` and `sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A10 -i network` output?

Comment: Ok, could you edit your question, add the information there and delete the comments, I can't read a thing like that.

Comment: Again, edit the question and add the information there. **Do not use comments!**

Comment: **This** is called comments. Where you are writing and I'm are called comments. The button says "Add Comment". If you need to add information you **[edit]** the question. Read this http://askubuntu.com/help/editing

Answer (score 2):

Got my ethernet connection, from the answer to [another user's question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308958).
I guess the instrumental bit was:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Even if this didn't complete, I believe it did remove the blacklist file which prevented the access to the drivers.
I believe this is a major bug in the installer: potential users 'try' ubuntu, check that it seems to work, then 'install' it and get cornered into a non-working system.
I'm surprised it doesn't get fixed after multiple people (probably 1%--the other 99% being thrown back to Windows) repeatedly report it.