# Wired connection problem for Ubuntu 13.10 using DELL VOSTRO

Tags: networking, drivers, 13.10, dell, wired

I am having a problem using wired connection for Ubuntu 13.10. The problem started suddenly. However I was able to solve it using the answer given in the following post:

[Ubuntu 12.04 Dell 6400 no network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308958/ubuntu-12-04-dell-6400-no-network?s=505ba01f-707e-4fe8-8865-a5a6d420f712#new-answer)

It worked perfectly. But now again I am unable to connect to the internet. I tried using the same solution but it was of no use. I have reinstalled the driver for Realtek Ethernet Controller (r8168 ==the latest version) using the answer given in this post:

[Wifi and Ethernet connectivity problems after upgrading to 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177083/wifi-and-ethernet-connectivity-problems-after-upgrading-to-12-04)

But these solutions are not solving my problem.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
sudo ifconfig :
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ac:6f:76:c1:2c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:985 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:95359 (95.3 KB)  TX bytes:149074 (149.0 KB)
          Interrupt:46 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1032 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1032 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:89902 (89.9 KB)  TX bytes:89902 (89.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:7c:8f:10:08:d0  
          inet addr:192.168.43.74  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::227c:8fff:fe10:8d0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10844956 (10.8 MB)  TX bytes:2728215 (2.7 MB)

=====================================================================
lsmod |grep r8168
r8168                 387138  0
```

============================================================================

```
 dmesg |tail

[ 3140.976810] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

[ 3156.224464] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain

[ 3156.233144] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:

[ 3156.233152] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)


[ 3156.233156] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)

[ 3156.233161] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)

[ 3156.233164] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)

[ 3156.233168] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)

[ 3156.233172] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)

[ 3171.265877] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Please tell us what exact symptoms you are getting. Any error messages? You talk about wired connections but have tagged this as wireless, are you using wired or not? Finally, please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo ifconfig` and `lsmod | grep r8101`.

Comment: You _are_ connected to the internet using your wireless. What makes you think you're not? What are the symptoms you're seeing? Are you actually attempting to connect with a wire?

Comment: i am unable to connect to the internet using wired LAN cable

Comment: OK, please unplug the cable, then plug it back in and run `dmesg | tail` and post the output here. Also, try `service networking restart` and see if that makes a difference. Finally, have you added `r8168` to `/etc/modules`? If you haven't do so, then restart and see if it works.

Comment: /etc/modules have r8168..restarted the network but still no connection possible.